# Difference between FreeBSD and Ubuntu

Tags: bsd

I want to know which differences between FreeBSD and ubuntu! Someone praise FreeBSD and someone praise Ubuntu and I would like to choose the best ! Which differences between FreeBSD and Ubuntu?

Comment: First what do want to accomplish, then decide which of the two delivers best!

Comment: Please use http://unix.stackexchange.com/ for this. They support BSD related questions; we don't

Comment: The question asks about difference between Ubuntu and FreeBSD, so it only partially asks about FreeBSD. Question may be a bit broad, but definitely not off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

The question should be "BSD vs Linux" (Gnu/Linux), If you read a little bit about their history you get a really better Idea how they are differ from each other, I  suggest having a look at these Wikipedia pages:

- [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD)
- [GNU Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Project)
- [Linux Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel)
- [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)

Typically Ubuntu is a Gnu/Linux based distribution, while freeBSD is a whole operation system from BSD family, they both are unix-like.

Linux distributions like Ubuntu are more bleeding edge which makes them a better option for home users, also Linux supports of hardware is much better than of BSD (sooner support of new hardwares).

Most of desktop environments and softwares are available for both of them, however in my opinion installing software in Linux distributions is much easier and faster than FreeBSD which most of the softwares should be installed by port system (source code). there are also binary packages available for FreeBSD which don't get regularly updated as I remember, I might be wrong).

Other nice articles to read:

- [10 differences between Linux and BSD](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-differences-between-linux-and-bsd/)
- [whats is the difference between Linux and bsd](https://www.howtogeek.com/190773/htg-explains-whats-the-difference-between-linux-and-bsd/)
- [Linux vs. BSD: Which Should You Use?](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-vs-bsd-which-should-you-use/)